# How do I have one thread that deletes from a HashMap and another that inserts?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have a hash:

```
let mut hash: HashMap<String, Vec<i32>> = HashMap::new();
```

and I start a thread:

```
thread::spawn(move || delete_from(&mut hash));

fn delete_from(m: &mut HashMap<String, Vec<i32>>) {
    loop {
        m.remove(a_key)
    }
}
```

this works great. I have a `sleep` statement in there (not shown) and it correctly makes `a_key` and deletes it from the `HashMap`. I can see the thread slowly removing each item when I print it out.

I want to start a 2nd thread:

```
thread::spawn(move || insert_into(&mut hash));

fn insert_into(m: &mut HashMap<String, Vec<i32>>) {
    loop {
        m.insert(a_string, a_vector);
    }
}
```

that is inserting. But when I add the 2nd thread I get:

> capture of moved value: `hash` [E0382]

What's the right way to set this up?

[The complete code](https://github.com/andrewarrow/tinted_paradise/blob/eaed5207b4d6d08d48525066e172d5d064a31917/practice.rs).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it is, the hashmap is moved into the first thread, so no other threads may access it. You'll need an `Arc` for shared ownership, so that multiple threads can access the map, as well as a `Mutex` for synchronization so that they aren't both trying to modify the map at the same time.

Here's what that would look like:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

let hash: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<String, Vec<i32>>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::new())); // initialize the map within an Arc (for sharing) and a Mutex (for synchronization)
let clone1 = hash.clone(); // clone the Arc so it can be owned jointly by multiple threads
let clone2 = hash.clone(); // clone the Arc so it can be owned jointly by multiple threads

thread::spawn(move || delete_from(&clone1));
thread::spawn(move || insert_into(&clone2));

fn delete_from(m: &Mutex<HashMap<String, Vec<i32>>>) {
    loop {
        m.lock().unwrap().remove(a_key); // lock the mutex, remove a value, unlock
    }
}

fn insert_into(m: &Mutex<HashMap<String, Vec<i32>>>) {
    loop {
        m.lock().unwrap().insert(a_string, a_vector); // lock the mutex, insert a value, unlock
    }
}
```

Comment: ah, thank u, I now finally understand rust. That was the last peice of info I was missing.